# Parsing Bash Array in Yaml

Tags: bash, ansible, yaml

In ansible playbook, I have to read one yaml file which contains the data like:

```
john: stu001
bob: stu002
william: stu003
```

This data is dynamic, there can be number of students with their ids. I want to read this yaml in my ansible play and needs the output like :

```
---
- name: Students Data
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include_vars:
        file: tmp/stuData.yml
        name: stuName
  - name: "Students Details"
    uri:
      url: "{{ some_api_server }}"
      return_content: yes
      body_format: json
      method: POST
      body:
         matchers:
           - name: john
             id: stu001
             age: NA
           - name: bob
             id: stu002
             age: NA
           - name: william
             id: stu003
             age: NA
         startsAt: "{{ st_time }}"
         endsAt: "{{ en_time }}"
         createdBy: abc@example.com
```

I have tried the following code for it:

```
---
- name: Students Data
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - include_vars:
        file: tmp/stuData.yml
        stuName: stuName
  - name: "Students Details"
    uri:
      url: "{{ some_api_server }}"
      return_content: yes
      body_format: json
      method: POST
      body:
         matchers:
         {% for k,v in stuName.items() %}
           - name: {{ k }}
             id: {{ v }}
             age: "NA"   
         {% endfor %}
         startsAt: "{{ st_time }}"
         endsAt: "{{ en_time }}"
         createdBy: abc@example.com
```

This is giving me syntax error in line after matchers. Can anyone please help me in writing the correct code.

Comment: Can you describe the yaml file after applied the `animals` variable?

Comment: I am sorry, I had some mistake in code. Now I have corrected it. So can you check now how to loop this animal variable to create this matcher collection dynamically.

Comment: YAML itself does not have _variables_, but you can deal with this on the bash level, by defining your YAML Code as a Here-Document and use bash variables. In each iteration of the bash loop, you therefore have a version of that YAML code for that particular animal, and can for instance write it to a file.

Comment: Can you add example for it?

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple script that writes the hashes, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat /tmp/xyz.sh 
#!/bin/bash
declare -A animals=(["moo"]="cow" ["woof"]="dog")
for i in "${!animals[@]}"; do
    echo "$i: ${animals[$i]}"
done
```

gives

```yaml
shell> /tmp/xyz.sh 
woof: dog
moo: cow
```

Then the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        xyz: "{{ lookup('pipe', '/tmp/xyz.sh')|from_yaml }}"
```

creates the dictionary

```yaml
  xyz:
    moo: cow
    woof: dog
```

Now you can format the data to any structure, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        matchers: "{{ xyz|dict2items }}"
```

gives the list *matchers*

```yaml
  matchers:
  - key: woof
    value: dog
  - key: moo
    value: cow
```

---

You can change the names of the attributes, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        matchers: "{{ xyz|dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='value') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  matchers:
  - name: woof
    value: dog
  - name: moo
    value: cow
```

---

Then, you can add the attribute *name* and put it into a list, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _list: "{{ [{'name': 'xyz', 'matchers': matchers}] }}"
```

gives the structure you're looking for

```yaml
  _list:
  - matchers:
    - key: woof
      value: dog
    - key: moo
      value: cow
    name: xyz
```

---

Q: *"**Pass this animal variable to yaml file**"*

A: Use *copy*, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/xyz.yml
        content: |
          - name: xyz
            matchers:
          {% for k,v in xyz.items() %}
              - name: {{ k }}
                value: {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/xyz.yml 
- name: xyz
  matchers:
    - name: woof
      value: dog
    - name: moo
      value: cow
```

, or you can use the created list, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/xyz.yml
        content: "{{ _list|to_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/xyz.yml 
- matchers:
  - {key: woof, value: dog}
  - {key: moo, value: cow}
  name: xyz
```

, or you can improve the format by the filter *to_nice_yaml*, e.g.

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/xyz.yml
        content: "{{ _list|to_nice_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat /tmp/xyz.yml 
-   matchers:
    -   key: woof
        value: dog
    -   key: moo
        value: cow
    name: xyz
```

---

Q: *"**Flow of the code is like firstly sh file will be executed that will call play.**"*

A: There is practically no difference. Read the file instead of running the command in the *pipe* lookup, e.g.

```yaml
shell> /tmp/xyz.sh > /tmp/xyz.txt
shell> cat /tmp/xyz.txt
woof: dog
moo: cow
```

Then the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        xyz: "{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/xyz.txt')|from_yaml }}"
```

creates the same dictionary

```yaml
  xyz:
    moo: cow
    woof: dog
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. My flow of the code is like firstly sh file will be execute that will call play which is a yaml file, then that yaml file will trigger task file which is also a yaml file. So I need this animal variable to be looped there in task file.

Comment: There is practically no difference. Change the lookup plugin from *pipe* to *file* and read the data from a file. I've added an example.

Comment: I got it, thanks. How to check the length of animal variable in sh file?

Comment: You're welcome. In Ansible use [length](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#jinja-filters.length). In sh, open a new question in sh and make it [mre] there.

Comment: I have update my question with what things I tried,  can you please look into it and let me know what's wrong with my task file?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to pass it "directly" from bash. I doubt it will really be of any use but it was fun to search

```sh
$ ansible localhost -m debug -a var=animals \
    -e "{\"animals\":{$(for k in ${!animals[@]}; do echo \"$k\":\"${animals[$k]}\",; done)}}"
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "animals": {
        "moo": "cow",
        "woof": "dog"
    }
}
```

Note that you can probably create a bash script or function to ease that processing, but I didn't try myself and I'll let you do it if you want to walk that path.

Comment: It will be great if you will help in knowing me how to consume it in my yaml file.

Comment: Like any other variable defined elsewhere. For a start, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: thanks, can you look into the question now and answer for it?